# Alterar valor das propriedades dependendo do seu tipo

Tags: c#, .net-5

Na minha aplicação rest eu recebo os valores via json que são convertidos para uma classe

Meu endpoit

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Pessoa/Adicionar")]
public JsonResult AdicionarPessoa([FromBody] PessoaCommand body)
{
     try
     {
     _svcAutentication.Autenticar(Request.Headers["Autentication"].ToString(), Request.Headers["DataBase"].ToString());

     body.TratarValoresRecebidos();

     _svcPessoa.Adicionar(body);

     return new JsonResult(body.TipoPessoa == "F" ? _svcPessoa.BuscarPorCpf(body.Cpf) : _svcPessoa.BuscarPorCnpj(body.Cnpj));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Response.StatusCode = 400;
          return new JsonResult(ex.Message);
     }
}
```

No envio da requisição, caso algum campo do json não seja preenchido, ela chegara na minha aplicação com o seu valor padrão, no caso, booleanos virão como falsos, tipos numéricos serão convertidos para 0, e strings para null e datas para 0001/01/01

A  função de tratar valores serve para converter os tipos strings q vierão null para string vazia "", e converter as datas que vieram 0001/01/01 para 1900/01/01 e transforma alguns campos de string q vieram preenchido em maiusculo

Como eu faço um trabalho repetitivo, queria saber se existe alguma maneira de eu ler todas as propriedades da minha classe e dependendo do tipo dela eu faço alguma manipulação, no caso a conversão das strings nulas para "", string preenchida com algum valor fazer um ToUpper (no caso do TipoPessoa e TipoAdvogado) e datas padrões (0001/01/01) para 1900/01/01

```
public class PessoaCommand
{
    public decimal CodigoCliente { get; set; }
    public string TipoPessoa { get; set; }
    public bool Advogado { get; set; }
    public bool Captador { get; set; }
    public bool Cobrador { get; set; }
    public bool Cliente { get; set; }
    public bool Fornecedor { get; set; }
    public bool Devedor { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string InscricaoEstadual { get; set; }
    public string InscricaoMunicipal { get; set; }
    public string Rg { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string TipoAdvogado { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public decimal GrupoSeguranca { get; set; }
    public decimal Atividade { get; set; }
    public decimal Contato { get; set; } 
    public decimal Oficial { get; set; } 
    public decimal Segurado { get; set; } 
    public decimal GrupoCliente { get; set; }
    public decimal Autor { get; set; } 
    public decimal Reu { get; set; }
    public string CodigoAlteracao { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAlteracao { get; set; }
    public string CodigoCriacao { get; set; } 
    public DateTime DataCriacao { get; set; }
    public decimal Filial { get; set; }
    public decimal Inativo { get; set; } 
    public int Localizador { get; set; } 
    public int Usuario { get; set; } 
    public decimal Filiais { get; set; }
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }
    public int Setor { get; set; }
    public decimal Amigavel { get; set; } 
    public decimal Juridico { get; set; }
    public decimal Horario { get; set; }
    public DateTime Admissao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Rescisao { get; set; }
    public decimal Banco { get; set; }
    public string Agencia { get; set; }
    public string Conta { get; set; }
    public int Cartorio { get; set; }
    public DateTime Admissao2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Rescisao2 { get; set; }
    public decimal GrupoCobranca { get; set; }
    public string DigitoConta { get; set; }
    public decimal Cpf { get; set; }
    public decimal Cnpj { get; set; }
    public string ArquivoMorto { get; set; }
    public decimal Cargo { get; set; }
    public decimal Ramal { get; set; }
    public decimal Empresa { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public decimal ValidaHorario { get; set; } 
    public decimal PosJuridico { get; set; } 
    public string Oab { get; set; }
    public decimal CarteiraFoco { get; set; }
    public string DigitoAgencia { get; set; }
    public string OpVar { get; set; }
    public decimal Pis { get; set; }
    public decimal UtilizaSoftPhone { get; set; }
    public decimal CarteiraWo { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public decimal TipoCentral { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscagemManual { get; set; }
    public decimal CentralAlternativa { get; set; } 
    public decimal Receptivo { get; set; } 
    public decimal MetaDiscador { get; set; }
    public string SapClienteNcNds { get; set; }
    public string SapClienteNrp { get; set; }
    public string SapFornecedorNds { get; set; }
    public int EmailFuncional { get; set; }
    public int TipoUsuario { get; set; }
    public decimal Fiador { get; set; }
    public decimal SegurancaGrupoCobranca { get; set; }

    public void TratarValoresRecebidos()
    {
        TipoPessoa = TipoPessoa?.ToUpper();

        if (InscricaoEstadual == null) InscricaoEstadual = "";

        if (InscricaoMunicipal == null) InscricaoMunicipal = "";

        if (Rg == null) Rg = "";

        if (Login == null) Login = "";

        TipoAdvogado = TipoAdvogado == null ? "" : TipoAdvogado?.ToUpper();

        if (Observacao == null) Observacao = "";

        if (CodigoAlteracao == null) CodigoAlteracao = "";

        if (DataAlteracao == new DateTime(0001, 01, 01)) DataAlteracao = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (CodigoCriacao == null) CodigoCriacao = "";

        if (DataCriacao == new DateTime(0001, 01, 01)) DataCriacao = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (Nascimento == null) Nascimento = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (Admissao == null) Admissao = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (Rescisao == null) Admissao = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (Agencia == null) Agencia = "";

        if (Conta == null) Conta = "";

        if (Admissao2 == null) Admissao2 = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (Rescisao2 == null) Rescisao2 = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01);

        if (DigitoConta == null) DigitoConta = "";

        if (ArquivoMorto == null) ArquivoMorto = "";

        if (Email == null) Email = "";

        if (Oab == null) Oab = "";

        if (DigitoAgencia == null) DigitoAgencia = "";

        if (OpVar == null) OpVar = "";

        if (Senha == null) Senha = "";

        if (SapClienteNcNds == null) SapClienteNcNds = "";

        if (SapClienteNrp == null) SapClienteNrp = "";

        if (SapFornecedorNds == null) SapFornecedorNds = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar [`Reflection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) para isso.

Com `Reflection` é possível tratar uma instância de objeto de forma genérica, sem conhecer o seu tipo e analisar seus membros (propriedades, métodos, etc).

Baseado no exemplo desse link: [system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-5.0), o código abaixo recebe uma classe e inspeciona cada propriedade. É um exemplo curto, mostro como mudar o valor de uma propriedade `DateTime` e `String`, basta fazer o mesmo para os outros tipos e com os valores que deseja:

```
PessoaCommand teste = new PessoaCommand();
teste.Agencia = "123";

ValidarValores(teste);

private static void ValidarValores(Object obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        // Se for data, seta a data atual 
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, DateTime.Now);
        }

        // se for string e estiver com o valor default, seta um valor
        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(String))
        {
            if (prop.GetValue(obj) == default(String)) prop.SetValue(obj, "valor default");
        }
    }
}
```

Pode ver um exemplo funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oWaIOL

Comment: quando o tipo for string, se eu quiser fazer um ToUper() apenas em uma propriedade, no caso, if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(String)) e dentro desse if fazer outra validação... Se nome da propriedade for TAL, então faz um ToUper()

Comment: basta fazer um `if (prop.Name == "NomeQueDeseja")`, mas isso iria deixar o método menos genérico. Para resolver seu problema isso estaria ok, mas se quiser reaproveitar eu sugiro implementar um `Action` :)

Comment: a função não precisa do parâmetro